# Prevent multiple web service calls via JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I'm starting to integrate some jQuery calls in my Classic ASP pages but want to prevent the user from clicking buttons multiple times and sending multiple server queries. What's a good practical way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends what your [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call's look like.

For example you could disable the button which sends the [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call using the `beforeSend` function. Then re-enable it when you either get `success` or an `error`:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            toggleBtn(obj);
        },
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: 'whatever',
        success: function(data) {
            // Do whatever with data....
                alert("While an alert is showing, the JS is paused, look at the button. After clicking ok, its going to be enabled.");
            toggleBtn(obj);
        },
        error: function() {
            // Do whatever with the error.....
            // Re-enable the button, you need to do this, otherwise on an error
            // the user couldn't try again without reloading the page.
            toggleBtn(obj);        
        }
    }); 
});
```

See a [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yJaQ/1/)

Use a simple wraper function to allow you to re-use the code:

```
function toggleBtn(obj) {
    if (obj.attr('disabled') == true) {
        obj.attr('disabled', false);
    }  
    else {
        obj.attr('disabled', true);    
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could attach a [`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) to the click event:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: 'whatever',
        success: function(data) {
            // Do whatever with data....
                alert("While an alert is showing, the JS is paused, look at the button. After clicking ok, its going to be enabled.");
        },
    }); 
}).ajaxStart(function() {
    toggleBtn($(this));
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    toggleBtn($(this));
});
```

See a [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yJaQ/)

Another way would be to disable ALL ajax call's whilst one is happening. To do this, you could give all your ajax buttons a class. Then attach the [`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) to the document:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(e) {
    toggleBtn($('.ajax'));
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    toggleBtn($('.ajax'));
});
```

See a [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yJaQ/4/)

***NOTE:** the alert is just to pause the execution of the JS so you can see the button is actually disabled, otherwise it would happen too quickly to see whats happening.*

Of course you could also add the option [`async: false,`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), which means the script will pause till it get's a result.

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/ - is a very nice jquery plugin that can be used for exactly this.

Or you can use the events available in jquery.

[ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

and

[ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

You could use these two to create a function of your own that you fires when an ajax call is made.